# Passing a list of files to XLConnect

Tags: r, for-loop

I've written a script based on a for-loop to read in columns of multiple .xls files, combine them to a single data frame, search for negative values and write a .txt file with these values and the name of the file.
The script works basically, but I have several hundred files to process, and it's a bit slow. This version of the script is only a basic framework for later statistical analysis, and I want to parallelize the execution to speed it up.
I've tried to avoid the for-loop by applying the function via lapply and the plyr-package, but had problems passing the file list to "readWorkSheetFromFile" (Error in path.expand (filename) : invalid 'path' argument).

Here is the working script:

```
require(XLConnect)
setwd(choose.dir())

input = list.files(pattern = ".xls$")

# creates empty data frame 
df = data.frame(Name=NULL, PCr=NULL, bATP=NULL, Pi=NULL)

for(i in seq(along=input)){
    data = data.frame(readWorksheetFromFile(input[i], sheet="Output Data", 
    startRow=2, startCol=c(10, 13, 16), endCol=c(10, 13, 16), header=TRUE))

    head(data, n = -1L)

    colnames(data) = c("PCr", "bATP", "Pi")
    data$Name = file.path(input[i])

    attach(data)
    df = rbind(data, df)
    attach(df)
    rm(data)
}

# searches for negative values in df and writes to txt file 
neg_val = subset(df, bATP<0 | Pi<0 | PCr<0)
write.table(neg_val, file = "neg_val.txt", sep = "\t", quote=F)
```

Any solutions to this problem, or other suggestions to speed up execution?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Your speed issues are probably due to your [lack of preallocation](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), not the for loop. (The idea that for loops are inherently slow in R is a bit of a myth.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't know why Martins code is not working on my data, but I've found another solution. It was about 4x faster in a first test than my original approach.

```
# load required packages
require(XLConnect)
# set working dir
setwd(choose.dir())

# creates list of files of chosen dir and all subdirectories
files = list.files(pattern = ".xls$", recursive=T, full.names=T)

data = do.call("rbind", lapply(files, function(fl) {
   # Read data from file
   data.tmp = data.frame(readWorksheetFromFile(file = fl, sheet="Output Data", 
                         startRow=2, startCol=c(10, 13, 16), 
                         endCol=c(10, 13, 16), header=TRUE))

  # deletes last row of data frame
  head(data.tmp, n = -1L)

  # add file names as column 
  data.tmp$File = file.path(fl)
  data.tmp
}))

# rename columns
colnames(data) = c("PCr", "bATP", "Pi", "File")
# list negative values 
neg.val = subset(data, bATP<0 | Pi<0 | PCr<0)
# write output file
write.table(neg.val, file = "neg_val.txt", sep = "\t", quote=F)
```

Thanks to all and best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0):

please find below a suggestion on how to potentially improve things a bit. Note that I'm providing a slightly more general example here such that others can easily reproduce.

```
require(XLConnect)

# *** Generate some dummy files ***

for(i in 1:10) {
  data = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000), ncol = 10))
  names(data) = LETTERS[1:10]
  writeWorksheetToFile(file = sprintf("test%s.xls", i), data = data, sheet = "data", header = TRUE)
}


# *** Process files ***

# Get files to process
files = list.files(pattern = "^test[0-9]+.xls$")
# Read chunks of data from files and subset
data.negative = lapply(files, function(fl) {
  # Read data from file
  data = readWorksheetFromFile(file = fl, sheet = "data", header = TRUE)
  # Which rows have all values < 0
  idx = apply(data, 1, function(x) all(x < 0))
  data[idx,]
})
# How many rows of all zeros does each chunk have?
nrows = sapply(data.negative, nrow)
# Combine data.negative into one data.frame
data.negative = do.call(rbind, data.negative)
# For each row add from which file it is originating
data.negative$File = rep(files, times = nrows)
# Write output file
write.table(data.negative, file = "neg_val.txt", sep = "\t", quote = FALSE)
```

The idea is to NOT subsequently rbind the data.frames which makes things slow (depending on the size of your data.frames). In your case I would suggest doing the read and subset via lapply and then combine the subsets together for writing to a file. Also note that you can easily switch the lapply to e.g. plyr's llply and hook a parallel backend to it for parallelizing that task (however your disk might be a bottleneck if you attempt many parallel reads).

Hope that helps.

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for my stupidity, but I didn't get it to work so far. If i try to read in my files I'm getting the error message: `data.negative = lapply(files, function(fl) {
+   data = readWorksheetFromFil .... [TRUNCATED] 
Error in apply(data, 1, function(x) all(x < 0)) : 
dim(X) must have a positive length`. If I try to make `data = as.data.frame(readWorkSheetFromFile ...`, I'm getting no error message, but an empty file. Hope you can help once more!

Comment: What version of XLConnect are you using? The latest (0.1-9)?

Comment: I'm working with the latest R and package versions. Your example is running perfectly, by the way.

Comment: Did you adapt the readWorksheetFromFile call as you had in your example (specifying start/end row/col accordingly?)